# How to add javascript to WebBrowser.NavigateToString()?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-7, browser

I develop an application which display HTML content and I need get information about height of document's content. So I want to add javascript function to my content and invoke it from c#.

My code is:

```
MyWebBrowser.NavigateToString(
    string.Format(@"
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
            </head>
            <body>
                <script>
                    function getHeight() { 
                        return document.body.clientHeight; 
                    }
                </script>
                <div>
                    {0}
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>", myContent);
```

The problem is it always throw `System.FormatException`. It's works correct if I remove the script part.

How can I change it to add javascript function correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the `{` and `}` in your function declaration

```
MyWebBrowser.NavigateToString(
string.Format(@"
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script>
                function getHeight() {{ 
                    return document.body.clientHeight; 
                }}
            </script>
            <div>
                {0}
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>", myContent);
```